# Populate ShipBy date in ShipStation.com from BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, integration, bigcommerce

I'm looking to write a script for ShipStation.com that will populate the ShipBy date for new orders placed from my store on BigCommerce. I'm struggling to figure out the best way to accomplish this. The data is apparently sent to ShipStation but they don't map it to a field because it isn't required in BigCommerce, so their support team says.

Can I access an event hook in BigCommerce to make a call to the ShipStation.com API to update/create this order? ShipStation.com has the API to accomplish this but I'm unclear on how to pull this off in BigCommerce. Is this an event I can get access to? Since I don't have access to the backend code on BigCommerce and I don't see it listed in the Event hooks for Stencil themes, I'm a little worried that I can't do this. Anyone have any tips or ideas?

I'm hoping to not have to write my own web application that sits in the middle, listening to BigCommerce for when orders are placed and then creating those orders in ShipStation.com. Seems like such overkill seeing as they already have a good integration, it is just missing this one field.

Comment: There is no current shipby date in the order schema from bigcommerce. Where are you looking at getting this data from or where do you or the customer supply it?

Comment: The customer supplies it. To the best of my knowledge, I believe BigCommerce can supply it in the order schema but ShipStation.com doesn't do anything with it. Customer support mentioned to me that for some platforms where it is required, they do have it. It shows up in the UI of BigCommerce dashboard under a product, there is an option for "Delivery/Event date" where you can require it, it then shows up on the product details page.

Comment: Yeah, so it would be in the order products subresource. They may not be grabbing those particular details so you can make a get request to the order's products array (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#order-product-object-properties) and capture the event date. You can then pass this to shipstation in whatever field is most appropriate.

Comment: Does that mean I will need to build my own little web app to run this script or is there an event hook on BigCommerce I can listen for when an order is placed? Or maybe another way to have the script run on BigCommerce without having to build and host my own web app?